# Is there a way to do this with Python xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I would like to create the equivalent of this VBA macro from excel in Xlwings:

```
    Sub sortononecol()
    Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("A4"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End Sub
```

I tried using the script below but got different results.

```
     last_row = ws.range('B' + str(ws.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
     ws.range("A4:N{row}".format(row=last_row)).api.Sort(Key1=ws.range("A5:A{row}".format(row=last_row)).api, Order1=1, Header=1)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a complete [mre], including sample input, expected output, and actual output, all as formatted text (not images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from your VBA code;
You want to select cell 'A4' have the current region selected and sort ascending handling a Header row.
In this example, rows 1 to 9 in column 'A' with row 1 (cell 'A1') as header. Current region from cell 'A4' is 'A1:A9'.

```
...
col_range = ws.range('A4').current_region  # using cell coordinate 
# col_range = ws.range(4, 1).current_region  # using row/col coordinate

ws.range(col_range).api.Sort(Key1=col_range.api, Order1=1, Header=1, Orientation=1)
```

Column sort example
[image]

Comment: Nice. Was going through your xlwings post. One quick question here. what is the use of current region being at A4 because the sort output would have been same even if we take A2 as current region?

Comment: @the-great I was duplicating the OPs VBA code where they selected current region from cell A4, **A4Range("A4").CurrentRegion**. In my example A2 would select the same range however for the OP if A2 was not in the [same] range as A4 it would fail to select what they wanted.